# How could I communicate asynchronously templates and views in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a Django application and in one of the views I have a loop which is controlled by a delay. My purpose is to change dynamically the delay value since my template using a form.

I give a pseudocode example below:

`temaplate.html`

```
<body>
    <form>
      # Here I want to input a value, and change the x_seconds value in the view.
    </form>
</body>
```

`views.py`

```
def myview():

    items = [...]    # A list with some items
    for item in items:
        print item
        delay(x_seconds)    # Delay after print the item to see the algorithm behaviour
```

The final objective is change the value of x_seconds dynamically since a form while the loop is iterating over the list.

Comment: Set a default value for `x_seconds` in your form and use the submitted form's `x_seconds` in the `delay` call?

Comment: I edited the question because I have seen its bad formulated. I want to change the value of x_seconds while the loop is iterating. If I have a list with  1 billion items, my purpose is change the delay to see different zones with different speed. For example, if I see a value that is interesting to me, set the delay to 2 seconds, and if the data is not interesting set the delay to 1 millisecond. That means the loop can have different delay values during the iteration.